On update google credentials, old access token is working with new credentials
I use google calendar apis in my app. First I get google calendar credentials file from user. Then Get access token using that credentials. Api's are now working, I am able to get google calendars.
After that I create a new project in google developer console and create creadentials for which google calendar api's are disabled. Then I use new project credentials with the old access token that is created before to get google calendars. Google calendars are still getting.
How the google calendars can get using the different project credentials for which google calendar api's are disabled and the access token that is created from the different credentials for which the google calendar api's are enabled?

Please edit your question and include your code.  Why do you want different projects
